# basic java read string to list and other functionality

Tags: java

I am trying to learn java so total newbie here.
Lets say for example we have a string

```
String file = "1,Cheese Burger,50;2,Pizza,70;3,Coke,20;4,Beer,20";
```

What I need to do is create a console based application to list all these items then add multiple items and display the price.

This is the code I have tried. I can add the numbers, I just don't know how to take the input from the user to a variable.

For example when I run the console application I want the user to input as many burgers as he wants. Then he is done he selects number 3.

Please be gentle

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String file = "1,Cheese Burger,50;2,Pizza,70;3,Coke,20;4,Beer,20";
        //split
        String [] elements = file.split(";");
        //convert string to list of string
        List<String> fixedLengthList = Arrays.asList(elements);
        //copy fixed to arraylist
        ArrayList<String> listOfString = new ArrayList<String>(fixedLengthList);

       int  p = 0;
        while (p != 5) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            for (String line : listOfString
            ) {
                System.out.println("1. Cheese burger 50");
                System.out.println("2. Pizza 80");
                System.out.println("3. View your bill");
                sc.nextInt();
                String[] items = line.split(",");
                String itemPriceString = items[2];
                double itemPrice = Double.parseDouble(itemPriceString);
                double burger = itemPrice;
                System.out.println(burger+burger);

            }
        }

   }
}
```

Comment: see the other methods that Scanner offers, like next(), or nextLine(). You can assign the returned value of those methods to a String variable, like `String line = sc.nextLine();` I hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm really sorry that I don't understand the problem exactly, but I'd like to recommend some tips to manage similar variables in a bundle.

Like the data structure in C++, such as the pair and tupe, java has a method of declaring 'Class'

```
 class Menu {
int order;       //for food order number
 String name;    // for food name,
int price;       //for food price

Menu(String name, int price){
  //following the 'Constructor' We can put data
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  }

}
```

Then, how can we use it?

By using List in this way,

```
       String file = "1,Cheese Burger,50;2,Pizza,70;3,Coke,20;4,Beer,20";

    //split
    String [] elements = file.split(";");

    List<Menu> foodMenu = new ArrayList<Menu>();        //init

    for(int i = 0; i< 4; i++) { //4 foods
        String [] line = elements[i].split(",");

        foodMenu.add(new Menu(Integer.parseInt(line[0]), //food order number
                        line[1],                         //food name
                        Integer.parseInt(line[2]))       //food price
                );
    }
   /*foodMenu[0] = 1, Cheese Burger, 50
    foodMenu[1] = 2, Pizza, 70 
    foodMenu[2] = 3, Coke, 20
    foodMenu[3] = 4, Beer, 20

    if you want to access a data you can use like this
    foodMenu.get(index).order / name / price ; */
```

Now, let's try through this new storage system let customers choose what to buy and pay for

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

class Menu { 
    int order;      //for food order number
    String name;    // for food name
    int price;      //for food price

    Menu(int order, String name, int price){
        //following the 'Constructor' We can put data
        this.order = order;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

}


public class StackOver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String file = "1,Cheese Burger,50;2,Pizza,70;3,Coke,20;4,Beer,20";

        //split
        String [] elements = file.split(";");

        List<Menu> foodMenu = new ArrayList<Menu>();        //init

        for(int i = 0; i< 4; i++) { //4 foods
            String [] line = elements[i].split(",");

            foodMenu.add(new Menu(Integer.parseInt(line[0]), //food order number
                            line[1],                         //food name
                            Integer.parseInt(line[2]))       //food price
                    );
        }
       //foodMenu[0] = 1, Cheese Burger, 50
      //foodMenu[1] = 2, Pizza, 70 
      //foodMenu[2] = 3, Coke, 20
      //foodMenu[3] = 4, Beer, 20

      //if you want to access a data you can use like this
      // foodMenu.get(index).order / name / price ;

   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    int price = 0; //for purchase price
    int  p = 0; //Great Init for avoiding NullPointerException
    while (p != 5) {
            System.out.println("Please Input number 1 to 5 to Order food or purchase");
            System.out.println("1. Cheese burger 50$");
            System.out.println("2. Pizza 80$");
            System.out.println("3. Coke 20$");
            System.out.println("4. Beer 20$");
            System.out.println("5. Beer 20$");

            p = sc.nextInt();   //customer will choose number

            if(p!=5) {  
                price += foodMenu.get(p-1).price;
                //add price of selected food!
            }

        }
    System.out.println("Ok, The price is "+price+"$ in total");
    System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
    }
}
```

[image]
^ExampleResult

I hope this answer will help you a little bit and if it's hard to understand, please leave a comment!
Have a peaceful day!

Comment: this helped me a lot thank you very much for the clear explanation. I will adjust my code,

Comment: I'm so glad that this answer is helpful!! Thank you for choosing and hope you have a peaceful day!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    // print the menu
    for (String menuItem : listOfString) {
        String[] item = menuItem.split(",");
        System.out.println(item[0] + ". " + item[1] + " " + item[2]);
    }

    // read the selection
    int selection = sc.nextInt();
    if (selection == 3) {
        // print bill
        break;
    }

    // get information of selected item
    String[] selectedItem = listOfString.get(selection);
    String itemName = selectedItem[1];
    int itemPrice = Integer.parseInt(selectedItem[2]);
}
```